# CaptchaImage.axd give 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am adding captcha image on my asp.net project.Its working properly on my system.But when i send same project to some other person then same code and captcha is not working on his system.

Its giving .axd 404 error.I am not able to find what causes the problem.we are testing code on local in visual studio in both system.

I am using this code:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-implement-Captcha-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Can you please suggest me what causes the issue.Thanks

Comment: We def. need a more detailed error description, stracktrace, screenshot. Give us as much detailed information as you can provide

Comment: @serv this is the error in console  ...Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:45629/CaptchaImage.axd?guid=e68b2442-5f53-4c24-a6b8-16d7aa4132fb

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add reference to ashx files as above link suggested.

```
<add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
```

Please do that. Also check that path is correct.